# Largura célula PdfPTable iTextShar MVC 4

Tags: c#, itextsharp

Estou a utilizar o [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) para criar PDF's na minha aplicação. No entanto tenho de recrear uma tabela, onde tenho de definir o tamanho para a uma coluna bastante reduzido. Segue a imagem que mostra o tamanho com que quero configurar a coluna:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando ao resto da criação da tabela está tudo bem, não consigo mesmo é definir esta largura.

**Código:**

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
table.WidthPercentage = 82.0f;
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Com a assinatura autógrafa, o signatário desta Auto-declaração garante ter cumprido estas condições:", fontetexto));
cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
cell.PaddingTop = 10f;
cell.Colspan = 2;
cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
table.AddCell(cell);
table.AddCell("1. ");
table.AddCell("Os óleos e gorduras vegetais velhos fornecidos são biomassa conforme o Decreto de biomassa.");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problema resolvido. Vi várias soluções na net onde diziam para definir a tabela da seguinte maneira:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(10);
table.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
table.TotalWidth = 500f;
table.LockedWidth = true;
float[] widths = new float[] { 100f, 4000f };
table.SetWidths(widths);
```

O resultado era sempre: 'Ficheiro corrompido'.
A solução passou então em definir o tamanho da tabela (o array `float`) logo ao criar a mesma:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(new float[] { 30f, 400f });
```